# Artifactory jfrog jenkins failed uploading artifacts by spec

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

Hi I am trying to upload multiple files into artifactory repo using my Jenkinsfile, Please find the snippet and error pasted below:
Artifactory Plug in version - 2.16.2 and Jenkins 2.138.2

snippet from Jenkinsfile and message from the logs

```
 def uploadSpec = """{
  "files": [
  {
   "pattern": "folder/test.py",
   "target": "reponame-local/folder/"
  }
 ]
}"""
                def buildInfo1 = server.upload spec: uploadSpec
```

I get the below error pasted all logs here Invalid object ID

```
    SEVERE: Failed to execute command Pipe.Flush(-1) (channel JNLP4-connect connection from 10.37.88.189/10.37.88.189:41732)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Invalid object ID -1 iota=25377
        at hudson.remoting.ExportTable.diagnoseInvalidObjectId(ExportTable.java:478)
        at hudson.remoting.ExportTable.get(ExportTable.java:397)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.getExportedObject(Channel.java:780)
        at hudson.remoting.ProxyOutputStream$Flush.execute(ProxyOutputStream.java:307)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:565)
        at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteBufferCommandTransport.processCommand(AbstractByteBufferCommandTransport.java:203)
        at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteBufferCommandTransport.receive(AbstractByteBufferCommandTransport.java:189)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onRead(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:187)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecv(ApplicationLayer.java:207)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecv(ProtocolStack.java:669)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processRead(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:369)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecv(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:117)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecv(ProtocolStack.java:669)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRead(NetworkLayer.java:136)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.NIONetworkLayer.ready(NIONetworkLayer.java:160)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$OnReady.run(IOHub.java:795)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Object appears to be deallocated at lease before Sun Nov 18 20:34:02 MST 2018
        at hudson.remoting.ExportTable.diagnoseInvalidObjectId(ExportTable.java:474)
java.lang.Exception: Error occurred during operation, please refer to logs for more information.
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.producerConsumer.ProducerConsumerExecutor.start(ProducerConsumerExecutor.java:84)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecsHelper.uploadArtifactsBySpec(SpecsHelper.java:71)
        at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:190)
    Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from xx.xx.xxx.xx/xx.xx.xxx.xx:41732
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
            at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
            at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1071)
            at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
            at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.executors.GenericUploadExecutor.execution(GenericUploadExecutor.java:52)
            at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.UploadStep$Execution.run(UploadStep.java:65)
            at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.UploadStep$Execution.run(UploadStep.java:46)
            at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
            at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
            at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

        Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed uploading artifacts by spec
            at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:194)
            at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:131)
            at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3085)
            at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
            at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
            at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
            at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I think that your logs (either Jenkins or build logs) should include an additional error message, hinting to the root cause of the problem. Can you please find and share this message? Also, are you using the latest version of the Artifactory Plugin?

Comment: added the additional error message

Comment: also I see a similar error https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-1025

Answer (score 0):

It seems wontedly created issue by infra. Please try with user having write access and these will only can resolved by Infra team.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).